# Using entity Framework with .NET Core and DB2

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, db2

Has anyone used .NET Core with DB2 and EF Core? We've tried to find compatible drivers, but none seem to exist. Has anyone found a way to use DB2 with .NET Core 3.0?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no core 3.0 or standard 2.1 support thanks to IBM's terrible .Net support.  Supposedly an alpha driver will be available in March 2020 if you contact their support.

You can some of the conversation at this [link](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=7be8e033-4c24-4de6-b52c-3db1647afe53&CommunityKey=ea909850-39ea-4ac4-9512-8e2eb37ea09a&tab=digestviewer&reply-inline=7be8e033-4c24-4de6-b52c-3db1647afe53&SuccessMsg=Thank%20you%20for%20submitting%20your%20message).

Comment: To follow up on this.  They did release a 3.1 alpha driver, though you need to contact their support to be given access to it and it can only be downloaded through their Passport Advantage pages.  Few bugs with it, but it does support basic value converters now, i.e. string trimming or smallInt fields to booleans.

Comment: IBM have released a provider compatible with EF Core 3.1 a few days ago in nuget.org.

Answer (score 5):

IBM have now released a [new version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.0.300/) `3.1.0.300` of `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore` on nuget that works with EF Core 3.1.

A couple of things I needed to do for it to work:

- Download new version of license file that targets DB2 version 11.5 from passport
  advantage

  - I don't know why this limitation exists, but our old 11.1 license simply did not work and the database was not upgraded at all.
- License file must be copied to `C:\Users\{YourUserNameHere}\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license`

  - For older versions, replace `buildTransitive` with `build`

I'm assuming the user has access to the IBM Passport Advantage, I don't know about trial licenses.

It was quite confusing to find where to download the license file, but I figured it out and will mention the steps here for anyone else who needs to do it:

- Determine which version of license is needed, in this case 11.5
- Go to: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/downloading-ibm-db2-version-115-linux-unix-and-windows
- Find the correct part number for you from the list, for me it was **CC6XNML**.
- Use the part number in the Passport Advantage software downloads page

  - Instructions: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/99203
- After that just download the lic file and place it in the library nuget installation directory mentioned above.

Note: It's still possible to use the older library with .NET Core 3.1, as long as EF itself is not updated to the 3.1 version. The problem is compatibily with EF 3.1, not .NET Core 3.1. As long as updating the EF nuget package to a newer version is avoided, things will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are packages for Db2 listed on the [Database Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) EF Core help page. I haven't used them, personally, but if they're listed there, they should work fine.

Comment: Okay, those are from 2018 and seem to support up to Core 2.x. So it's probably fair to say that no .NET Core 3.0 drivers yet exist for DB2 - unless IBM is developing any?

Comment: The NuGets target .NET Standard 2.0, which means they're compatible with anything that implements .NET Standard 2.0, i.e. .NET Core 2.x *and* 3.x. It may have simply not needed any changes since 2018. The providers are very low-level. The main work (and most of the changes) happens in EntityFrameworkCore and EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.